# Setting and getting with uitable

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

I'm creating a Nx3 uitable since it seems much easier than multiple text-edits when N is high. I initialised the columns as cell array in order to initially obtain an 'empty' table.

```
hinitial = cell(N,1);
hfinal = cell(N,1);
hporosity = cell(N,1);
DataInput = [hinitial;hfinal;hporosity];
ColumnName = {'n_Initial','n_Final','Porosity'};
ColumnFormat = {'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric'};
ColumnEditable = [false true false];

htable = uitable(fig,'Units','pixels','Position',[20 20 260 204],...
         'Data', DataInput,...
         'ColumnName', ColumnName,...
         'ColumnEditable', ColumnEditable);
```

1) With this pushbutton I want to loop-print the data into the first column.

```
function uploadbutton_Callback(source,eventdata) 
S = load('n.mat');
for K = 1:N
set(htable(K,1),'Data',num2cell(S.n(K)));
end
end
```

But this does the printing only for the first row of that column. Then this error is displayed.

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in bandprovaprog/uploadbutton_Callback (line 122)
set(htable(K,1),'Data',num2cell(S.n(K)));
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.
```

2) In the second column I want to manually input data, then save the results in a mat file using a pushbutton. My effort so far is this:

```
function donebutton_Callback(source,eventdata) 

m = zeros(1,N);
 for J = 1:N
 m(J) = str2double(get(hfinal{J},'String'));  
 end
save('m.mat','m');
end
```

3) Last column again uses set to print in the third column so I think I can do it once I know how to do 1)

EDIT2: edit of donebutton_Callback

```
function donebutton_Callback(source,eventdata) 

 m = zeros(1,N);
 m(1:N) = str2double(htable.Data(1:N,2),'Data'); 
 save('m.mat','m');
end
```

I want to put the content of the second column into m.mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your `set` command seems dodgy, setting the `Data` like that will attempt to set *all* of the data I think. Instead simply assign to the specific Data element

```
function uploadbutton_Callback(source,eventdata) 
    S = load('n.mat');
    for K = 1:N
        htable.Data{K,1} = S.n(K);
    end 
end
```

Better still, vectorise your code and avoid looping

```
function uploadbutton_Callback(source,eventdata) 
    S = load('n.mat');
    htable.Data(1:N,1) = num2cell(S.n(1:N));
end
```

Similarly for (2), don't use `get`, simply access the data as shown above.

---

**Edit:**

Your new problem is the following. You are creating 3 Nx1 cell arrays, then concatenating them to pass as data to your table. When trying to edit column 2 of your data, you can't because you get the following error

> Warning: Table data is not editable at this location.

This is because (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078744/3978545)) you are not providing enough data to populate all columns of your table. This is confusing at first, until you look in your workspace...

[image: workspace]

You are expecting that variable to be Nx3, but instead it is 3Nx1! You need to use commas to concatenate rows, instead of semi-colons to concatenate columns when forming `DataInput`:

```
DataInput = [hinitial, hfinal, hporosity];
% Equivalently to remove ambiguity, you could use: 
% DataInput = horzcat(hinitial, hfinal, hporosity)
```

Once you update this, the table behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! When I try to do (2) and type a number into the second column though it tells me my table is not editable in that location, even if I set that column to editable.

Comment: In (2) you're not editing the table, so I have no idea what you mean... Please post the actual error message

Comment: I'm just trying to manually enter my data in the table then pressing done to save them in a mat file. Though when I enter a value in the table it disappears when I press enter and move to the next one. This orange warning appears: `Table data is not editable at this location`.

Comment: My donebutton_Callback is now edited, and another error appears `Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

Comment: Update it in your question too then (note that it's an edit and add it to the end) or I cannot guess why you are getting an error...

Comment: yes I updated it in EDIT2. To summarize: I can't get the values I input in the second column to stay visible, since when I press enter to move to the row below the value disappears. Then if I try and press the Done pushbutton to save values in the m.mat file, the 'index' error appears.

Comment: You don't need the `,'Data')` in your code, or the intitialisation of `m` as you're assigning to the whole variable anyway. Simply use `m = str2double(htable.Data(:, 2));`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't still insert the data without the warning showing up and the data disappear after I enter them.. my problem is really similar to this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148841/how-can-l-assign-values-in-uitable]

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to do 2) and 3). I had to change the input format to 'char' otherwise NaN was showing up in the m.mat file. Is there a way to align the values of the char column (the second one) to the right? Otherwise I'll leave it like this, thanks again!